# Delete dynamically allocated derived objects - Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subclass

I cannot figure out how to delete the dynamically allocated subclasses through the basepointer. The allocation is in the App-class and how do I delete the allocated objects from withing the main-method?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {

public:
   virtual void print() = 0;
   virtual ~Base() {
      cout << "Base destructor\n";
   }
};

class Sub1 : public Base {

public:
   void print() {
      cout << "I am Sub1!\n";
   }
   ~Sub1() {
       cout << "Sub1 destructor\n";
   }
};

class Sub2 : public Base {

public:
   void print() {
      cout << "I am Sub2!\n";
   }
   ~Sub2() {
       cout << "Sub2 destructor\n";
   }
};

class App {

public: 
   App(Base *&b) {
      b = new Sub1;
      b = new Sub2;
   }
};


int main() {

   Base *b;
   b = NULL;

   App app(b);


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: An object can't be both `Sub1` and `Sub2` at the same time. These are sibling classes, not parent/child. You would need to derive e.g. `Sub3` from both `Sub1` and `Sub2` to do that. In your code `b = new Sub2` causes the previously allocated `Sub1` to be leaked.

Comment: `b = new Sub1;
      b = new Sub2;` Leaves you with a memory leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Good point. As an aside however, can the first write to `b = new Sub1;` be eliminated by the compiler in this case?

Comment: @Alejandro No I doubt so, because of possible side effects might occur on the constructor call.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Could I possibly delete the subclasses through some kind of downcast?

Comment: @java I think you are trying to do something, what you don't understand properly actually.

Comment: You don't need to "delete the subclasses", you have a virtual destructor, the compiler will take care of everything.

Comment: The pointer to Sub1 is lost, sucks , but the pointer that does survive, Sub2, should be deletable in main with `delete b;` The compiler will make sure a Sub2 is deleted along with it's Base.

Comment: @user4581301 - is it really lost? I could put all this in a std::vector <Base*> and then loop the vector. But I am not interested in that here :(

Comment: @java if you don't keep a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, it's lost. If you assign the object to a pointer, then reassign the pointer to another object, it's lost. If you assign both objects to different elements of a vector, you're good. But you should rethink the way you are doing this. If class App is creating the subclasses, it should also have the responsibility of maintaining and deleting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum fix for you leaks would be:

```
class App {

public: 
   App(Base *&b) {
      b = new Sub1;
      delete b;      // This is your only chance since the next statement overwrites the pointer.
      b = new Sub2;
   }
};


int main() {

   Base *b;
   b = NULL;

   App app(b);

   delete b;

   return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't seem like a very sensible program. You really need to figure out what you're trying to do with Sub1 and Sub2. You can't have a single pointer pointing to two separate objects at the same time.

Furthermore, you would be better off learning to use std::unique_ptr, since that keeps ownership of what it points to and thus deletes it when appropriate.

So using std::unique_ptr the minimum change to your code is:

```
class App {

public: 
   App(std::unique_ptr<Base> & b) {
      b.reset(new Sub1);
      b.reset(new Sub2);
   }
};


int main() {

   std::unique_ptr<Base> b;

   App app(b);

   return 0;
}
```

There are no manual delete statements. And there are no memory leaks.

(The probably useless Sub1 issue is still there, but that's a design issue you have to figure out since I don't know what you want your program to actually do in the end.)

Comment: didnt show you the real code which is based on the decorative pattern. So every component (dynamically allocated) holds a pointer to the next component in the list. All this is done in the app-class where b is the basecomponent created in main. Thanks!!!